# How do i match left div to the right div?

Tags: javascript, css

The scenario is simple, my goal is to stretch the **left div** to the **right div's** height

[image]

to

[image]

the code, I'm using bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
     <input placeholder="left div" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
     <input placeholder="" />
     <input placeholder="" />
     <input placeholder="" />
     <input placeholder="right div" /> /* This is the right div */
     <input placeholder="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure whether to use CSS or javascript to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.left input {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 left">
    <input placeholder="left div" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 right">
    <input placeholder="" />
    <input placeholder="" />
    <input placeholder="" />
    <input placeholder="right div" />
  </div>
</div>
```

edit

```css
.left input {
height: 100%;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  background: palegoldenrod
}

.pull-right {
align_items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 left">
    <input placeholder="left div" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <input placeholder="" />
    <input placeholder="" />
    <input placeholder="" />
    <input placeholder="right div" /> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-6 col-offset-6">
    <input placeholder="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there's another input underneath the right div?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use flexbox:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.col-6 input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
.col-6:first-of-type input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
     <input placeholder="left div" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
     <input placeholder="" />
     <input placeholder="" />
     <input placeholder="" />
     <input placeholder="right div" />
  </div>
</div>
```